# Resource.h editing in VS2010 C++ not working with anhksvn

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn

I'm trying to figure out why anhksvn is mangling the editing of resources in Visual C++. The files resource.h and project.rc are marked as svn:needs-lock since they can't be easily merged . When editing resources anhksvn correctly asks for locks on both files and editing is fine. When the editing is saved however the resource.h is marked as "new" instead of "modified".

Of course there is already an existing resource.h file in exactly the same location in the repository so on commit it fails saying the file already exists. The file in the working copy itself is perfectly valid and compiles without problems. The only solution I've found is to make a copy of resource.h, delete the file and update to get the old file back then copy the new file over and commit which works fine although it's a giant pain.

I'm trying to figure out why this is happening. SVN knows the file exists and can normally function fine. However, for some reason sometime it thinks when the resource editor saves over resource.h the file never existed and has to be added, even though it knows the file exists on any commit operation.

Edit: I eventually found the problem was with file case. The project had Resource.h but the file was actually resource.h. Since file case in windows is ignored Visual Studio is fine with it. However, when the VS2010 saves the resource.h file it passes the proper file case to anhksvn and it thinks there is a new file Resource.h being added. When it examines the actual file it sees resource.h, anhksvn sees it is already added therefore can't be added again. I had to make a copy of resource.h, rename the file under SVN then delete it. I then renamed the copy resource.h and added it again to the project. The project then had file case correct and the problem was solved.